# Splunk - how to parse JSON ingested from Azure blob?

Tags: splunk, splunk-formula, splunk-calculation

I have file called "30 Jan 2020.json" that contains 2 records:

```
[
  {
    "Sender": "John",
    "Recipient": "Alice",
    "Subject": "Hello",
    "MessageDate": "10 Jan 2020"
  },
  {
    "Sender": "Jane",
    "Recipient": "Bob",
    "Subject": "Holiday"
    "MessageDate": "15 Jan 2020"
  }
]
```

My props.conf file is

```
[_json_for_azure]
INDEXED_EXTRACTIONS = json
KV_MODE = json
LINE_BREAKER = ([\r\n]+)
NO_BINARY_CHECK = true
category = Structured
description = JavaScript Object Notation format. For more information, visit http://json.org/
disabled = false
pulldown_type = 1
```

and in inputs.conf I specified

```
[mscs_storage_blob://mycontainer]
account = mycontainername
blob_mode = append
collection_interval = 60
container_name = mycontainer
sourcetype = mscs:storage:json
```

But when this data is ingested, I only get entries called _Time, and when I expand any of them, they show all records json as single string as row. I want the actual data such as each Sender, Recipient, Subject to be ingested as individual entries.  So when I search for individual sender such as John, I want only the single row to be returned, rather than returning whole file contents. This is the behaviour when using Azure Splunk plugin. When I loaded the file directly via "Add data" option from the main menu, the file is parsed correctly with individual entries.